# What is the deepest man-made underground tunnel?

Tags: earth, geophysics

[image: http://bm.img.com.ua/img/prikol/images/large/4/0/258204_603914.jpg]

What is the deepest tunnel in the Earth's surface?

I have meet numbers, around 300km.

**What is the main problem to make tunnel more deeper? What is the problem with 1000km?**

Comment: If I have made mistake with the branch of stackexchange, moderator, please, move my question to the right one.

Comment: Are you interested in the deepest borehole or the deepest structure that most people would call a "tunnel"? The answers differ by more than an order of magnitude.

Comment: Deepest man-made mine, both, where human has made his step and where only drill did something.

Comment: Moreover, my question is: What is the main problem with making underground tunnel, under 1000km, like on the picture ^

Comment: The first question could be googled. I think that the last part should be removed.

Comment: My main question is: What stops humans to discovery the depths of the Earth? pressure of the air, temperature of the Earth's core, hardness of rocks?

Comment: The answer to the second part of your question is heat. The deeper we dig the closer we get to the molten core and the hotter it gets. Of course there are various other answer in specific circumstances, poison/acidic gases etc.

Comment: Your last question is probably best suited for [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: [Lakes and Oceans](http://www.xkcd.com/1040/). And if you haven't yet, look up the [Kola Superdeep Borehole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole).

Comment: The last part about secret government programs is definitely off-topic and should be removed; otherwise the question risks being closed to primarily opinion based.

Comment: Being great to move to skeptics, otherwise.

Comment: The second one is appropriate here. You can ask the last one on [skeptics.se].

Comment: Skeptics mod here, the question would not be appropriate for Skeptics. We require questions to be about [notable claims](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-does-notable-mean), which this one is not.

Comment: I don't know what you're asserting, but if we are talking about depth and feasibility, 1000km and 300km are insane figures. Wikipedia lists the _longest_ tunnel at 154km (Thirlmere Aqueduct. this is _horizontal_ length), and the _deepest_ borehole at 12km.

Answer (score 5):

The present version of the question is suitable to be asked and answered in the Physics community. We are not able to drill a hole too deep into the Earth for two reasons: temperature and pressure.
Temperature: Look at the [temperature profile of Earth](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/ldeo/v1011x-1/jcm/Topic3/Topic3.html), which is copied here.
[image]
Roughly at 70km deep, temperature is ~1000°C. At this temp, the drill bit, usually made of iron, is too soft to hold its structure, let alone to drill.
Pressure: Again at 70km, the pressure is 20000 atm. 1 atm = 1 kg/cm². For a surface area of 1 m², it's 2 x 10^8 kg of force. No tunnel can be made strong enough to stand it.
Just for the sake of arguing, if we go deeper than 100km, we are about to reach the mantle of the Earth, Mantle is either made of lava or at least semi-fluidic. So, I would say, building a city or a culture inside Earth is a like a pie in the sky.

Comment: Is really the pressure applying like that? I mean, stone is not a fluid, so I expect the ground itself to absorb most of the pressure.